# Sublime snippet does not tab complete after deleting previous snippet

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

In SublimeText 3 build 3083, tab completion of snippets breaks under odd conditions. Repro steps are:

1. Tab-complete a snippet (let's say `co` --> `console.log(this)`, but any will do)
2. Then change my mind delete it with `ctrl+shift+k`
3. Then add a new line with `ctrl+shift+enter`
4. Then type and try to tab-complete a new snippet

At this point, the snippet will not tab complete and instead the cursor travels to the beginning of the following line. This is true for all snippets, whether from a package or of my own creation, and happens anywhere in a file with any syntax highlighting configuration.

I realize it might sound like a really weird edge case, but I delete and insert lines *all* the time so this happens to me regularly.

[I made a quick video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByMeR_pUUZB5TWVCNkk1TlRQdW8/view?usp=sharing) to show this behavior if that's helpful.

Comment: I can't replicate this using Build 3095 or Build 3083 on OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: Hmmmmm...weird. If it's helpful, I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. I also just repro'd it with javascript, js babel, and python snippets

Comment: OK, I'll fire up my Ubuntu 15.10 VM and see what I can see...

Comment: Sorry, I still can't replicate with 3083 or 3095 on Ubuntu. I'd suggest reinstalling Sublime and seeing if that gets you anywhere...

Comment: Must be something particular about my setup...I'll try from scratch and see what happens